# Escape slashes when sending command output to an array

Tags: linux, shell-script, zsh, wildcards, escape-characters

In my current project, I am trying to take the output from `git branch -r` to an array in zsh, as follows:

```
% all_branches = ("${(@f)$(git branch -r)}")
```

However, when I run this command, I get the following error message on the terminal:

```
zsh: bad pattern: (  origin/Backplane-Broken-Links
```

I'm inferring that zsh is taking issue with the forward slash in the branch name. Is there a way I can process the forward slashes (as well as other special characters, if I run into any others) when sending the output from git into my array?

Comment: Are you sure the issue isn't the whitespace around the assignment operator ` = `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array assignment syntax in `zsh` (like in `bash` which borrowed that syntax from `zsh`) is:

```
array=( value1 value2
 value3...)
```

There can't be whitespace on either side of `=` (though there can be (space, tab or newline) inside the `(...)` which are used to delimit the words as usual, and those words making up the array members).

So you want:

```
all_branches=("${(@f)$(git branch -r)}")
```

Or:

```
all_branches=( "${(@f)$(git branch -r)}" )
```

Or:

```
all_branches=(
  "${(@f)$(git branch -r)}"
)
```

Whichever style you prefer.

```
all_branches=(${(f)"$(git branch -r)"})
```

Would also work. Placing the whole expansion in `"..."` combined with the `@` flag is when you want to preserve empty elements. I don't think git branch names can be empty, and note that anyway `$(...)` strips *all* trailing newline characters, so empty branches would be removed anyway if they were at the end of the output. We still need `$(...)` to be quoted though to prevent `$IFS`-splitting.

Incidentally, `array = ()` would be the start of the definition of both the `array` and `=` function:

```
$ array = ()
function> echo test
$ array
test
$ =
test
```

While:

```
array = (foo|bar)
```

Would be running the `array` command (if found) with `=` and the files that match the `(foo|bar)` glob pattern (if any) as argument.

But here, your `("${(@f)$(git branch -r)}")` doesn't form a valid glob pattern, nothing to do with *slashes*.

For completeness,

```
array = ( value1 value2 )
```

is valid syntax in the `rc` shell (the shell of Research Unix V10 and plan9). In that shell, you can't do `echo =` which gives you a syntax error. You need to quote the `=`.